# 1.7 MHz Full bridge driver circuit for mist maker validation

Tags: h-bridge, high-frequency, full-bridge

I'm building an ultrasonic mist maker that can support 10 ceramic discs with a resonant frequency of 1.7MHz. I found the following circuit online, unfortunately, I'm a beginner in circuit design and due to COVID and time constraints I cannot order these parts and test the circuit. It'd be great If someone can validate the circuit logically. I'll order a finalized PCB using the same design and then test it out.

As far as I know, TLC555 can be used to drive MOSFETs up to 1.7MHz but I doubt if there can be problems due to high frequencies in the MOSFETs.
Here's the link to the easyeda design page: https://easyeda.com/319ashwin/ultrasonic-mist-maker

[image]

[image]

```
[enter link description here][3]
```

Thanks in advance! Much appreciated.

Comment: Signal 1 and Signal 2 must be swapped on one side, there is no proper dead time generator, critical solution for 1.7 MHz